# 750 ml sparking water bottle for wine?

Tags: bottling, wine

I've brewed a half dozen batches of beer, and I am thinking of trying my hand at making some wine for the first time. Most likely a Red. We go through a lot of 750 mL glass water bottles. I would start saving them if I knew I could bottle wine in them.

I don't mind getting a corker and trying a bottle to see if its feasible. What I am more curious about is the affect of the bottles' color, shape and maybe other things I don't know about.

Here's the bottle I'm talking about. 
[http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/images/B001CTLQPG/ref=dp_image_0?ie=UTF8&n=3760901&s=hpc](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001CTLQPG)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the neck diameter for screw top water bottles is smaller than corked bottles. That is, I don't think a cork will fit that bottle. If you can find a closure that gives a good seal, the other factors shouldn't matter, though without the atmosphere exchange provided by a cork, the wine will not "age" in the bottle. Since the glass is clear, keep the bottles in a dark place.